# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x' while importing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

in Python 3 I try to import module (which imports another module) and I'm getting *ModuleNotFoundError*. My main module looks as follows:

```
from next_folder import adding
adding.add(1)
```

Then in the folder `next folder` I have two other modules. The first one is `adding.py`:

```
import substracting

def add(a):
    b = 1
    d = substracting.substract(20)
    c = a+b+d
    print(c)
```

The second one (in the same folder) is `substracting.py`:

```
def substract(c):
    d = c-1
    print(d)
    return d
```

While running `main.py` I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from next_folder import adding
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\next_folder\adding.py", line 1, in <module>
    import substracting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'substracting'
```

Could you help me modify this code so the `main.py` actually works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative import in that case

```
from . import substracting
```

In python 3 relative imports are supported only in the form from . import submodule

This would have worked as well:

```
import next_folder.substracting as sub

def add(a):
    b = 1
    d = sub.substract(20)
    c = a+b+d
    print(c)
```